# GoogleAppMeasurement 8.9.1 - No Matching Framework

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, maui

I've been experimenting with `.NET MAUI` to get a feel for it and see how it compares to `Xamarin.Forms`.

When trying to build and deploy the `ios` app, I am constantly receiving this error:

> Xamarin.Shared.targets(137, 3): No matching framework found inside
> '/Users/bryce/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework'.
> SupportedPlatform: 'ios', SupportedPlatformVariant: 'simulator', SupportedArchitectures: 'ARMv7'.

I have confirmed that the `GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework` file exists. I have even deleted the entire `XamarinBuildDownload` folder and all subdirectories, as well as the `.nuget` folder and all subdirectories. Nothing seems to solve this issue.

This project targets `.net7.0, .net7.0-android,` and `.net7.0-ios`. I have attached a screenshot of the nuget packages I am currently using on this project.

Best I can understand, this issue is saying that the only supported ios simulators are those using an ARMv7 architecture. But I'm not certain what that means exactly, and why this is an issue in `MAUI` and not in `Xamarin.Forms`.
I'd appreciate some help understanding this error, why it happens, and what I can do to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: You should publish the application to make sure it runs on deploy machine.  The error indicates that the runtime version for Core 7.0 is not installed on the deploy machine.  Publish will install the runtime version.  You can also manually install the runtime from : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: I created a  maui app and installed the nugets you shared, but I couldn't reproduce the problem. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?  But you can first try to clean your solution and rebuild your app again.

Comment: @jdweng I ran ```dotnet --version``` in terminal, and it tells me I have ```7.0.302``` installed.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have tried manually deleting the ```obj``` and ```bin``` folders, as well as using the ```Build > Clean Solution``` option within Rider. 
Unfortunately, none of these have solved my problem. 

I'd love to provide steps to reproduce, but I'm afraid I don't know what they are. I've been slowly working my way through errors while trying to get unit tests functioning, and this was the latest in a long line of problems.

Comment: I would try updating following : https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios I did not check the release notes.  You may find something in the notes.